# C++ Sorting the “percentage” of two paired integer arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have a program with 2 "paired" integer arrays newNumerator[ ], and newDenominator[ ] which both have 9 integers in them. I wrote a function that sorts them in ascending order (lowest percentage or 'ratio' to highest), however it outputs the elements in the same order as they were before, and doesnt sort it at all.  Here is the code, and sortData is the function that is (supposed) to sort it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

typedef int arrayType[];

void readData(int numerator[], int denominator[], int size);
void reportData(arrayType, arrayType, int);
void reportOverall(int numerator[], int denominator[], int size);
void cleanData(int* numerator, int* denominator, const int size, int *newNumerator, int *newDenominator, int &newSize);
void reportMin(int newNumerator[], int newDenominator[], int newSize);
void sortData(int newNumerator[], int newDenominator[], int newSize);
void hrule();
int main()
{
    const int size = 12;
    int numerator[size];
    int denominator[size];
    int newSize = 12;
    int newNumerator[newSize];
    int newDenominator[newSize];


    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(1);

    readData(numerator, denominator, size);
    reportData(numerator, denominator, size);
    reportOverall(numerator, denominator, size);

    hrule();

    cleanData(numerator, denominator, size, newNumerator, newDenominator, newSize);
    cout << "There are " << newSize << " scores that are not bonuses:\n";
    reportData(newNumerator, newDenominator, newSize);
    reportMin(newNumerator, newDenominator, newSize);
    hrule();
    sortData(newNumerator, newDenominator, newSize);
    cout << "The scores from highest to lowest are: " << endl;
    reportData(newNumerator, newDenominator, newSize);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void readData(int numerator[], int denominator[], int size)
{
    ifstream dataIn;
    dataIn.open("data.txt");
    if(!dataIn)
    {
        cout << "File not found\n";
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    int count;
    for(count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        dataIn >> numerator[count];
    }
    for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        dataIn >> denominator[count];
    }

    dataIn.close();
}

void reportData(arrayType numerator, arrayType denominator, int size)
{
    int count;
    for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        if (denominator[count] == 0)
        {
            cout << "Score " << (count + 1) << " is " << numerator[count] << "/" << denominator[count] << " = " << "Bonus points!\n";
        }
        else
        {
            double percent = 100.0 * static_cast<double>(numerator[count]) / denominator[count];
            cout << "Score " << (count + 1) << " is " << numerator[count] << "/" << denominator[count] << " = " << (percent) << "%\n";
        }
    }
}

void reportOverall(int numerator[], int denominator[], int size)
{
    int count;
    int totalNumerator = 0.0;
    int totalDenominator = 0.0;

    for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        totalNumerator += numerator[count];
    }
    for (count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        totalDenominator += denominator[count];
    }

    double overallPercent = 100.0 * static_cast<double>(totalNumerator) / (totalDenominator);
    cout << "Total Points Earned (numerators): " << totalNumerator << endl;
    cout << "Total Points Possible (denominators): " << totalDenominator << endl;
    cout << "Overall Grade: " << overallPercent << "%\n";
}

void cleanData(int* numerator, int* denominator, const int size, int *newNumerator, int *newDenominator, int &newSize)
{
    int count;
    int count2 = 0;

    for(count = 0; count < size; count++)
    {
        if(denominator[count] != 0)
        {
            newNumerator[count2] = numerator[count];
            newDenominator[count2] = denominator[count];
            count2++;
        }
        else if(denominator[count] == 0)
        {
            newSize--;
        }
    }

}

void reportMin(int newNumerator[], int newDenominator[], int newSize)
{
    double minimum;
    int count;
    int location = 0;
    double quotient;
    for(count = 0; count < newSize; count++)
    {
        quotient = 100.0 * static_cast<double>(newNumerator[count]) / newDenominator[count];
        if (count == 0 || quotient < minimum)
        {
            minimum = quotient;
            location = count;
        }
    }
    cout << "The lowest earned percentage grade is " << newNumerator[location] << "/" << newDenominator[location] << " = " << minimum << "%\n";
}

void sortData(int newNumerator[], int newDenominator[], int newSize)
{
    int temp1;
    int temp2;
    bool swap;
    int count = 0;
    double percentageLeft = 100.0 * static_cast<double>(newNumerator[count]) / newDenominator[count];
    double percentageRight = 100.0 * static_cast<double>(newNumerator[count + 1]) / newDenominator[count + 1];

    do
    {  swap = false;
        for(count = 0; count < (newSize - 1); count++)
        {
            if(percentageLeft > percentageRight)
            {
                temp1 = newNumerator[count];
                newNumerator[count] = newNumerator[count + 1];
                newNumerator[count + 1] = temp1;

                temp2 = newDenominator[count];
                newDenominator[count] = newDenominator[count + 1];
                newDenominator[count + 1] = temp2;

                swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while (swap);
}

void hrule()
{
    cout << "\n****************************************\n\n";
}
```

Data file-

```
72 49 23 5 9 10 6 16 26 54 14 55
75 50 25 0 10 0 0 20 30 55 15 60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're computing your `percentageLeft` and `percentageRight` outside your loop.  Those values never change as you are swapping things.

You probably want them as the first line inside your for loop.

Because the first two don't need to be swapped, it thinks none of the elements ever need to be swapped.  If the first two DID need to be swapped, your program would run forever, as the if statement `if(percentageLeft > percentageRight)` would always be true and `swap` would always be set to true leading to an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you, dont know why I didnt see that to begin with.